# Is there intractive GUI for igraph?

Tags: graph, ubuntu-12.04, igraph, graph-modelling-language

Is there a way to use **igraph** other than from command line in ubuntu?
(i mean a GUI for using it).My intention is to add weight to edges in a .gml file

Answer (score 1):

http://igraph.org/r/doc/aaa-igraph-package.html
visit the website it may be helpful to you...

Comment: is the knowledge of c/c++ enough to use it?

Comment: please help me to install igraph in R.....................i tried and installed R 3.2.3 when i try installing igraph using :install.packages("igraph") it gives me > warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("igraph") :
  installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status
s

Comment: i  doubts if it is because R version greater than 3.0.0?